# SQL String throwing error on Concatenating Fields

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox

The following SQL code:

```
Private Sub EnableRowsource()
Dim sRowsource As String

Select Case lstReasons

Case 13                                                     
    sRowsource = "SELECT NRType, NRReason, (NRType & " - " & NRReason) As Concat FROM TBLnonroutine WHERE NRProcess='Bene' ORDER BY NRReason asc"
    
    cboNRReason1.RowSource = sRowsource
    cboNRReason2.RowSource = sRowsource
    cboNRReason3.RowSource = sRowsource
End Select

End Sub
```

Is giving me a Type Mismatch error in Access. The SQL string is within the code of an Access DB Form. Can someone help?

Comment: Is this being built by the form?  or just called by it?  How are you doing this can you show a bit more code.

Comment: Just being called by it. It's a case statement based on the selection on a listbox. The click event calls the Function based on your selection. I'll update the code to include the whole function.

Comment: My goal is to display 2 columns in the listbox after update. Currently it only displays 1 column

Comment: You are trying to subtract two strings, the 2nd half from ""SELECT NRType, NRReason, (NRType & ""

Comment: `sRowsource = "SELECT NRType, NRReason, (NRType  &  " & """ - """ & " & NRReason)......`

Comment: That did it! Thanks!!

Comment: A single apostrophe would do it also: `"SELECT NRType, NRReason, (NRType & ' - ' & NRReason) As Concat ...` - like the one used for 'Bene'